# android, got FIS_AUTH_ERROR after update firebase-messaging to firebase-messaging:21.1.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

It has been working with

```
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'
```

and using old code:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId
    .addOnCompleteListener(
        OnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                 Log.e(TAG, "fetchPushToken: getInstanceId failed", task.exception)//<=== printout the exception and return from here after update to 21.1.0
                      
            } else {
                  // got token ...
            }
        })
```

after change to api `'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0'`, it is failing with the same old code.

And also tried [new way](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#retrieve-the-current-registration-token)

```
     try {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(
            OnCompleteListener() { task ->
               Log.e(TAG, "FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().token.onComplete(task). task.isSuccessful: ${task.isSuccessful}")
               if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                   Log.e(TAG, "fetchPushToken().OnCompleteListener.onComplete() failed", task.exception) //<=== printout the exception and return from here
                   return@OnCompleteListener
                }
           }
        )
     } catch (ex: Throwable) {
                    Log.w("+++","New FirebaseMessaging.getToken() exception next: $ex")          
     }
```

the exception:

```
    java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
        at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.handleResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@21.1.0:7)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.lambda$extractResponseWhenComplete$0$GmsRpc(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@21.1.0:1)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc$$Lambda$0.then(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:3)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseIidExecutors$$Lambda$0.execute(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:8)
        at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzz.execute(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.zzd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzr.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource.setResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzq.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@16.0.0:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzs.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@16.0.0:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzf.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cloud-messaging@@16.0.0:45)
        at com.google.android.gms.cloudmessaging.zzi.handleMessage(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Comment: Same problem here. Did you solve it?